# How do I find out what the DynaLoader "library reference" is referencing?

Tags: perl, module

Perl keeps a database of external dynamically loaded libraries by their file handles in `@DynaLoader::dl_librefs` how do I find out what the library is that `DynaLoader` keeps the handle to?

```
sub f {
  my $h = shift;
  # something that gives me a name, or caller or something useful?
  return $name;
};

map f($_),  @DynaLoader::dl_librefs;
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

[DynaLoader::bootstrap](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/714a461a2ab3017f19ea0f7bbb4934b2309d3aa8:/ext/DynaLoader/DynaLoader_pm.PL#l296) doesn't save the name of the file it loads (`$file`).<sup>[1]</sup>

The handles themselves are system-dependent handles. For example, on Windows, they are `HMODULE` values returned by `LoadLibraryExA` (dynamically linked) or `GetModuleHandle` (statically linked). On that system, you could use [`GetModuleFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx).

---

1. However, it does associate the path with a sub named `bootstrap` in the module's package. You can use the following snippet to find the path of the library of a specific DynaLoader-using module.

   ```
   use B qw( svref_2object );

   my $module_name = 'Foo::Bar';

   my $glob = do { no strict qw( refs ); *{$module_name.'::bootstrap'} };
   my $code = *$glob{CODE}
      or die("Module $module_name not loaded or doesn't use DynaLoader\n");

   my $path = svref_2object($code)->FILE;
   ```